# Insert in to MYSQL with PHP and AJAX not working

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms

I have created a simple form with php and AJAX. when the data is submitted the row is added to the database, however doesn't display on the page unless refreshed.

No errors are displayed.

**Update:** the alert I added in the success is now showing. However the data is still not showing without a page reload.

Any help is much appreciate.

AJAX:

```
$("form#message_form").submit(function() {

    var form = $(this);
    var url = "message.php"; // the script where you handle the form input.

    $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: url,
           data: $("input.input_styling").serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
            dataType: 'html',
           success: function(data)
           {

              alert('Checking if working...');

           }
         });

    return false; // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.

});
```

HTML:

```
<form action="" id="message_form" style="text-align:right;margin:0;"> 
    <input class="input_styling" type="text" name="infomation" /> 
   <button name="submit" class="submit_icon" type="submit"> > </button>       
</form>
```

message.php (Not really needed, but just in case)

```
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); // <== add this line

$sql = "INSERT INTO test (id, infomation)
VALUES ('".$_POST["id"]."','".$_POST["infomation"]."')";


if ($dbh->query($sql)) {

}
else{
echo "Ops! something went wrong...";
}

$dbh = null;


?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well i just ran this and it worked... The only thing i changed was the url, so check if you are linking the file correctly.
And a retoric question -  did you include JQuery?

```
    $("form#message_form").submit(function() {

    var form = $(this);
    var url = "http://httpbin.org/post"; // the script where you handle the form input.

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: $("input.input_styling").serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function(data)
        {
            alert('Checking if working...');
        }
    });

    return false; // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your JS to;

```html
$("form#message_form").submit(function() {

    var form = $(this);
    var url = "message.php"; // the script where you handle the form input.

    $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: url,
           data: $("form#message_form").serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
            dataType: 'html',
           success: function(data)
           {

              alert('Checking if working...');

           }
         });

    return false; // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.

});
```

if you need only "infomation" value;

```html
$("form#message_form").submit(function() {

    var form = $(this);
    var url = "message.php"; // the script where you handle the form input.

    $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: url,
           data: "information=" + $("input[name=information]").val(), // Get Information Value
            dataType: 'html',
           success: function(data)
           {

              alert('Checking if working...');

           }
         });

    return false; // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.

});
```